# jQuery modal dialog on page load

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm just trying to do a simple modal message on page load. There are tons of posts on doing this but I still can't seem to make it work.

I have this in the head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function() {                         
 $("#ModalMessage").dialog({modal: true});  
});
</script>
```

and in the body

```
<div id="ModalMessage" title="Test" style="display:none;">
yadda yadda yadda
</div>
```

I thought that was all that was needed, but all I get is a blank page, any idea?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script tags in the head are out of order.  JQuery should be first, then jquery-ui.  This would prevent jquery-ui (and hence the dialog plugin) from running.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog is default hidden. Try to put the autoOpen = true.

```
$("#ModalMessage").dialog({modal: true, autoOpen : true});
```

Otherwise you need to trigger the open event:

```
$("#ModalMessage").dialog("open")
```

Comment: `autoOpen: true` is the default value as writtent in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-autoOpen)